# Android NDK with Qt not able to locate header files

Tags: android, qt, android-ndk, qt-creator

I am trying to deploy a Qt app to an Android device, though I receive the error about  missing `stdlib.h`. I found out that this library is actually inside sub directory `tr1` of includes. I modified the `include<stdlib.h>` to `include<tr1/stdlib.h>`. After this I encountered the error for `locale.h`. This files doesn't seem to be present anywhere in the NDK.

The app works fine if build for Desktop as the Linux GCC has all files in proper hierarchy.

Any fixes?

Comment: Take a look at http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/45095 -- have you installed and prepared all toolchains correctly?

Comment: Got it, did same mistake of downloading wrong platform version.

Comment: You can write answer to your own question. Write how have you solved your issue, and what to do/not to do. Then you can mark your question as accepted, so you'll get some points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I resolved the issue. It was just the **wrong Android NDK build** I downloaded. My system architecture is x86_64 and the Android architecture is x86. The build I downloaded was that x86_64 Android. Make sure when downloading the **target** platform is your Android architecture.

Also, one might find several solutions recommending to create stand-alone build using **make-standalone-toolchain.sh** script and setting **CXX** home to this build and as well as set "sysroot". **Please do not do it**. It's not at all required. Just set the NDK path from Android option from Qt itself. That shall be enough.